# How do I get query string parameters from an Owin context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, oauth, instagram-api

When working against the instagram API, it requires the client to capture `?code=[some code]` from a successful OAuth response:

> **Step Two: Receive the redirect from Instagram**
>
> Once a user authorizes your application, we issue a redirect to your redirect_uri with a code
>   parameter to use in step three.
>
> `http://your-redirect-uri?code=CODE`

By default the OWIN middleware causes a redirect to `/signin-instagram` where the request is handled and then passed on to a new path that I choose (eg `/oauth/instagram`) where I get access to an OWIN context.

Because of the chained redirects the `code` querystring value is lost and it seems that I need a way to retrieve it from the OWIN context, but I can't find one.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that you don't. The owin provider should be (and is for Instagram) fetching anything relevant on the querystring and insert it into the `Claims`